# Where can I find my Playstation Plus expiration date?

Tags: ps3, psn, playstation-plus

I have a Playstation Plus account in the US market since July 2010. I purchased a whole year and I believed that it will expire around October 2011 but even today in december the wallet was not charged with it.

Where can I find my Playstation Plus expiration date?
Is somewhere in the market or in some web page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you counting in the 60+ days given with the Welcome Back package after the hack and the downtime? That may be why you haven't been charged yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see it under :

Account Management
-> Transaction history
   -> List of services -> Playstation Plus